# Is there any sudoku logic on 6's?

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

[image: sudoku puzzle]

I find this sudoku puzzle very difficult. I think there is some logic on 6's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top middle $3\times3$ box has only two unfilled cells, the $1$ and $2$, so let's start there with a What If assumption. I decided to assume that

> the top cell is 1 and the bottom one is 2, and proceed as follows:
>
>  [image]
>
>  After this, we reach a contradiction in the bottom right $3\times3$ box, because $9$ can't be anywhere.

From this contradiction, we know how to fill the top middle box, therefore all three middle columns, and you can go from there.